# Error in UseState - Line 11:24: Unexpected empty object pattern no-empty-pattern

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm a begginer at react.js and i just made this code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import "./App.css";

const App = () => {
  //const mensagem = "OLÁ MUNDO";
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("INITIAL VALUE");
  
  return (
    <>
      <div id='my_div' className="container">{message}</div>
      <button onClick={{} = setMessage("OTHER VALUE")}>
        Click here to change the message.
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Can anybody tell me what is wrong? I think i'm using something obsolet.

Thank you!

I was expecting to see the message changing, but this is not happening.

Comment: `{} = setMessage("OTHER VALUE")` Did you mean to create a function? Ie, `() => setMessage("OTHER VALUE")`

Comment: Just a typo, you used curly braces instead of parentheses in the `onClick` function, and you need a fat arrow `=>` to make it a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a function to handle button click. Inside this function you can change the state.

```
<button onClick={() => setMessage("OTHER VALUE")}>
    Click here to change the message.
</button>
```

or you can create a function early and call when button click

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import "./App.css";

const App = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("INITIAL VALUE");
  
  const changeState = () => {
    setMessage("OTHER VALUE")
  }
  
  return (
    <>
      <div id='my_div' className="container">{message}</div>
      <button onClick={changeState}>
        Click here to change the message.
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
export default App;
```